# Aura Component not visible on Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an Aura Component (not LWC) on the Opportunity record page in 2 different production Orgs, and I want to debug the JavaScript of the component in both orgs.

In one of the Orgs I can see the JavaScript file on the chrome DevTools like this:
[image: dev tools ok]

On the other org, I cannot see this JavaScript file on this path, or in anywhere else:
[image]

I already tried to enable the Debug Mode and to the user, but didn't work as well. Actually, on the Org where I can see the JS file, Debug Mode is also disabled.

Is there any permission/option that i have to enable in order to see it on dev tools?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this post. Perhaps this is the same issue with this link.

[Facing issue in debugging LWC Javascript with Chrome DevTools](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380016/facing-issue-in-debugging-lwc-javascript-with-chrome-devtools)

Comment: That was exactly the source of the problem. Thanks a lot!!