# How to avoid problem with debugging LWC Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scratch-org-definition-file, javascript-debugging, security-settings

Due to some recent changes, first:

- Enabling by default `Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components`
- Enable Stricter Content Security Policy

it becomes impossible to debug LWC Javascript files since even you put `debugger` statement inside, it never stops in Chrome Debugger tools.

I tried to use Grzegorz Skaruz and Sara Morgan [suggestions](https://saramorgan.net/2022/10/17/workaround-for-issue-debugging-lwc-in-chrome-dev-tools-after-winter-2023/) to include `"lockerServiceNext": false` settings in scratch org definition settings like following:

```
{
    "orgName": "Development Manual",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": [],
    "language": "en_US",
    "settings": {
        "securitySettings": {
            "sessionSettings:": {
                "lockerServiceNext": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to create a scratch org using these settings, I receive the following error:

> Error (1): A scratch org was created with username
> test-patlatustest@example.com, but the settings failed to deploy due
> to:  Error parsing file: Element or attribute do not match QName
> production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.

Also, I think that I really need to include

```
    "securitySettings": {
        "sessionSettings:": {
            "lockerServiceCSP": false
        }
    }
```

but any of configuration fail with the same error

> Error (1): A scratch org was created with username
> test-patlatustest@example.com, but the settings failed to deploy due
> to:  Error parsing file: Element or attribute do not match QName
> production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.

Is there any workaround or fix to this problem?

Comment: Turning off LWS isn't necessarily a fix--it will be enabled everywhere eventually when LS is retired. A root cause analysis should be done in order to report the bug to salesforce.com. I'll take a look at it over the weekend and see if I can find something.

Comment: well, maybe it is not a fix, but the only available workaround at the moment, and my question is more about how to enable that workaround, not really about what the workaround is

Comment: @sfdcfox there is a different question which asks actually what is the fix or workaround https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380016/facing-issue-in-debugging-lwc-javascript-with-chrome-devtools and disabling LWS is an accepted answer there

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm debugging more or less just fine in my sandboxes with LWS turned on, but only when Debug Mode is also enabled. The only annoyance seems to be that sometimes the source map is one line off, which makes it more of a challenge, but I don't think I've encountered this particular bug in an org.

Comment: debug mode sometitmes make really hard to debug since pages become non-responsive. Have you tried without a debug mode?

Comment: Debugging with Salesforce Debug Mode is more of a challenge, certainly, but I think it's just being able to take advantage of the full range of tools available; breakpoints, source formatting, ignoring library scripts, that sort of stuff. Also, the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_use.htm) can be useful for everything Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only option here is to create a file `force-app/main/default/settings/Security.settings-meta.xml` with the following body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sessionSettings>
        <lockerServiceCSP>false</lockerServiceCSP>
    </sessionSettings>
</SecuritySettings>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sessionSettings>
        <lockerServiceNext>false</lockerServiceCSP>
    </sessionSettings>
</SecuritySettings>
```

and perform push or deploy